# pdf is created from google slide, but with the markers populated (via GAS)

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

The code below basically maps columns from a spreadsheet to a couple of markers I got on a google slide.
It generates copies of the google slide template, updates them with the row's data and I actually need it to be in pdf form to be emailed later.
The pdf files are created in the destination folder, with the right file names, but the markers within them are "empty". Later on, I will have to delete these google slide files, but the challenge here now is to have the pdf files correctly created.

Appreciate your time.

```
function mailMerge(templateID,ssID, sheetName, mapped, fileNameData, emailCol, rowLen = "auto"){
  //Properties Services is Google Script Storage. 
  //This clears out the storage. 
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lista de Participantes");
  
  
  //Get number of rows to process
  rowLen = (rowLen = "auto") ? getRowLen()  : rowLen;
  
  const range = sheet.getRange(7,1,rowLen,sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns());
  const matrix = range.getValues();

  const fileNameRows = getFileNameRows()
  

  for(let i = 1; i < rowLen; i++){
    if (matrix[i][1] == true && matrix[i][27] != "Sim") {
    let row = matrix[i];
    //Get the title for the file.
    let fileName = buildFileName(row)    
    
    //Creates a copy of the template file and names it with the current row's details.
    let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);
    
    //Replaces all the text place markers ({{text}}) with current row information. 
    updateFileData(row, newDoc.getId());
        
    //Save new File ID and email to Properties service.
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
                     .setProperty(newDoc.getId(),row[emailCol]);

    // 5. Export the temporal Google Slides as a PDF file.
    newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
    DriveApp.getFolderById("folder ID").createFile(newDoc.getBlob());
    
    }
    };
```

Besides the code above, I go this script file within the same container/Spreadsheet, where I map the columns whose data I want to generate a google Slide for. each column of data I refer to as marker.

```
/*###################################################################
 * Maps the relationship between the Google Sheet header and its location
 * for each column along with it's corresponding Google Slide Doc template name.
 * 
 * To update change the sheet, col and doc:
 * ***
 * {
 *   sheet: << Your sheet header
 *   col: << The column on the google sheet with the above header
 *   doc: << the corresonding name in double braces {{name}} in your Slide template
 * }
 * ***
 *###################################################################
 */
const mappedDocToSheet = [
  {
    sheet:"Nome",
    col:2,
    doc:"primeiroNome"
  },
  {
    sheet:"Sobrenome",
    col:3,
    doc:"sobrenome"
  },
  {
    sheet:"COD. CERTIFICADO",
    col:9,
    doc:"codigo"
  },
  {
    sheet:"Curso",
    col:10,
    doc:"curso"
  },
];
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `markers` in your question. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike! Just added the script I use to populate the "markers" with the spreadsheet's data. The main challenge here is to have the pdf generated updated just as the copy of the google slides are. thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you add the values of Google Slides and create it to PDF data and `newDoc` is the Google Slides and also my understanding of your question is correct, when `SlidesApp.openById(newDoc.getId()).saveAndClose();` is added after the line of `// 5. Export the temporal Google Slides as a PDF file.`, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose)

Comment: It just worked! Arigato!
How can I mark this comment as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You add the values of Google Slides and create it to PDF data
- `newDoc` is the Google Slides

In order to achieve your goal, please use `saveAndClose`. For your script, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please add the following script to your function of `mailMerge` as follows.

```
// 5. Export the temporal Google Slides as a PDF file.
SlidesApp.openById(newDoc.getId()).saveAndClose();  // <--- Added
```

#### Reference:

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose)